# Connection on $T\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds, connections

Let $\nabla$ be a connection on the tangent bundle $T\mathbb{R}^n$. Now, I need to show that there exist smooth function $C_i: \mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n\times \mathbb{R}^n$, $i=1,\dots ,n$ such that

$$\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i} + C_i$$

for all $i$, where $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ are the coordinate vector fields.

Can someone give me hints how to solve this. I also don't quite understand what is meant by this formula as this $C_i$ is a matrix, whereas  $ \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}$ is a vector field and $\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}} $ is a map taking a vector field and giving a vector field.

**Attempt**: I computed that the j-th row of the matrix $C_i(p)$ is given by $(\nabla_{\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}})(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j})(p)$. Is that true?

Comment: Matrices are also maps taking vector fields to vector fields, as is the component-wise partial derivative in a fixed coordinate system.

Comment: My idea was to define $C_i$ by putting the partial derivative to the l.h.s. And then I can calculate the components of the matrix by acting it on a arbitrary vector field $X=f^i \partial_i$. Is that the right attempt?

Comment: @Abbie_beginner: Yes, your attempt is correct.

Comment: And is my result (see in question) also true?